# Nhibernate not-null property references a null or transient value Tec.Core.Model.Budget.oInvestmentCode

Tags: c#, xml, nhibernate

Good morning,

I am very new to NHibernate. I would like to use it in my new project, but I have encountered a problem with foreign key references. I am unsure as to why this problem may be happening.

The error message displayed was: `not-null property references a null or transient value    Tec.Core.Model.Budget.oInvestmentType`

Here is my table schema:

[image]

Here is my mapping file

### Airport

Airport.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">   
<class name="Tec.Core.Model.Airport, Tec.Core" table="tblAirport" lazy="false">
    <id name="ID" column="AirportID" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="AirportCode" column="AirportCode" />
    <property name="AirportFullName" column="AirportFullName" />

    <bag name="Budgets" table="tblBudget" inverse="true" cascade="save-update">
      <key column="AirportID" />
      <one-to-many class="Tec.Core.Model.Budget, Tec.Core" />
    </bag>
</class> 
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Airports.cs

```
public class Airport:Entity<int> 
{
    private string _airportCode="";
    private string _airportFullName="";
    private IList<Budget> _airportBudgets = new List<Budget>();

    private Airport() { }
    public Airport(string AirportCode, string AirportFullName) {
        this._airportCode = AirportCode;
        this._airportFullName = AirportFullName; 
    }                
     public  string AirportCode  {
        get { return _airportCode; }
        set { _airportCode = value; }
    }
    public  string AirportFullName {
        get { return _airportFullName; }
        set { _airportFullName = value; }
    }
    public IList<Budget> Budgets {
        get { return new List<Budget>(_airportBudgets).AsReadOnly(); }
        protected set { _airportBudgets = value; }
    }
    public void AddBudget(Budget air_budget){
        if (air_budget != null && !_airportBudgets.Contains(air_budget)){
            air_budget.oAirport = this; 
            _airportBudgets.Add(air_budget);
        }
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(){
        return (GetType().FullName + "|" + _airportCode.GetHashCode()).GetHashCode();
    }

}
```

### InvestmentCode

InvestmentCode.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">   
<class name="Tec.Core.Model.InvestmentCode, Tec.Core" table="tblInvestmentCode" lazy="false">
    <id name="ID" column="InvestmentCodeID" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="InvCode" column="InvestmentCode" />
    <property name="InvCodeNote" column="InvestmentCodeNote" />

    <bag name="Budgets" table="tblBudget" inverse="true" cascade="save-update">
      <key column="InvestmentCodeID" />
      <one-to-many class="Tec.Core.Model.Budget, Tec.Core" />
    </bag>
  </class> 
</hibernate-mapping>
```

InvestmentCode.cs

> public class InvestmentCode: Entity 
>       {
>
> ```
>     private string _investmentCode="";
>     private string _investmentCodeNote="";
>     private IList<Budget> _lstinvestmentCodeBudgets = new List<Budget>();
>
>     private InvestmentCode() { }
>     public InvestmentCode(string investmentCode, string InvestmentCodeNote) {
>         this._investmentCode = investmentCode;
>         this._investmentCodeNote = InvestmentCodeNote ; 
>     }      
>     public string InvCode {
>         get { return _investmentCode ; }
>         set { _investmentCode  = value; }
>     }
>     public string InvCodeNote {
>         get { return _investmentCodeNote ; }
>         set { _investmentCodeNote  = value; }
>     }
>     public IList<Budget> Budgets {
>         get { return new List<Budget>(_lstinvestmentCodeBudgets).AsReadOnly(); }
>         protected set { _lstinvestmentCodeBudgets = value; }
>     }
>     public void AddBudget(Budget investment_code_budget) {
>         if (investment_code_budget != null && !_lstinvestmentCodeBudgets.Contains(investment_code_budget)){
>             investment_code_budget.oInvestmentCode = this; 
>             _lstinvestmentCodeBudgets.Add(investment_code_budget);
>         }
>     }        
>     public override int GetHashCode(){
>         return (GetType().FullName +"|"+ _investmentCode.GetHashCode()).GetHashCode();
>     }
> }
> ```

### InvestmentType

InvestmentType.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">   
<class name="Tec.Core.Model.InvestmentType, Tec.Core" table="tblInvestmentType" lazy="false">
    <id name="ID" column="InvestmentTypeID" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="InvestmentTypeNote" column="InvestmentTypeNote" />    

    <bag name="Budgets" table="tblBudget" inverse="true"  cascade="save-update">
      <key column="InvestmentTypeID" />
      <one-to-many class="Tec.Core.Model.Budget, Tec.Core" />
    </bag>
</class> 
</hibernate-mapping>
```

InvestmentType.cs

> public class InvestmentType: Entity {
>
> ```
>     private string _investmentTypeNote="";
>     private IList<Budget> _lstInvestmentTypeBudgets = new List<Budget>();
>
>     private InvestmentType() { }
>
>     public InvestmentType(string InvestmentTypeNote){            
>         this._investmentTypeNote = InvestmentTypeNote ; 
>     }
>     public string InvestmentTypeNote {
>         get { return _investmentTypeNote ; }
>         set { _investmentTypeNote  = value; }
>     }
>     public IList<Budget> Budgets {
>         get { return new List<Budget>(_lstInvestmentTypeBudgets).AsReadOnly(); }
>         protected set { _lstInvestmentTypeBudgets = value; }
>     }
>     public void AddBudget(Budget investment_type_budget)  {
>         if (investment_type_budget != null && !_lstInvestmentTypeBudgets.Contains(investment_type_budget)){
>             investment_type_budget.oInvestmentType = this; 
>             _lstInvestmentTypeBudgets.Add(investment_type_budget);
>         }
>     }
>     public override int GetHashCode(){
>         return (GetType().FullName + "|"+ _investmentTypeNote.GetHashCode()).GetHashCode();
>     }
> }
> ```

### Budget

Budget.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">   
<class name="Tec.Core.Model.Budget, Tec.Core" table="tblBudget" lazy="false">
    <id name="ID" column="BudgetID" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="BudgetAmount" column="BudgetAmount" />
    <property name="BudgetYear" column="BudgetYear" />

    <many-to-one name="oAirport" column="AirportID"
      class="Tec.Core.Model.Airport, Tec.Core" not-null="true" />
    <many-to-one name="oInvestmentCode" column="InvestmentCodeID"
      class="Tec.Core.Model.InvestmentCode, Tec.Core" not-null="true" />
    <many-to-one name="oInvestmentType" column="InvestmentTypeID"
      class="Tec.Core.Model.InvestmentType, Tec.Core" not-null="true" />  
</class> 
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Budget.cs

> ```
>    public class Budget:Entity<long> 
>    {
>     private float _budgetAmount;
>     private int _budgetYear;
>     private InvestmentType _investmentType;
>     private InvestmentCode _investmentCode;
>     private Airport _airport;
>
>     public Budget() { }
>     public float BudgetAmount {
>         get{return _budgetAmount; }
>         set{_budgetAmount = value;}
>     }        
>     public int BudgetYear {
>         get{return _budgetYear; }
>         set{_budgetYear = value;}
>     }        
>     public Airport oAirport{
>         get{return _airport; }
>         set{_airport = value;}
>     }        
>     public InvestmentType oInvestmentType{
>         get{return _investmentType; }
>         set{_investmentType  = value;}
>     }        
>     public InvestmentCode oInvestmentCode {
>         get{return _investmentCode ; }
>         set{_investmentCode = value;}
>     }
>     public override int GetHashCode(){
>         return (GetType().FullName + "|" + _airport.GetHashCode() +"|"+ _investmentCode.GetHashCode()+"|"+ _investmentType.GetHashCode()).GetHashCode();
>     }
>
> }
> ```

And in my Default.asp.cs

I have following code :

```
        Airport objA = new Airport("NA", "New Airport")
        InvestmentCode objIC = new InvestmentCode("1000", "ABCD");
        InvestmentType objIT = new InvestmentType("Capex");

        Budget objBg = new Budget();
        objBg.oAirport = objA;
        objBg.oInvestmentCode = objIC;
        objBg.oInvestmentType = objIT;
        objBg.BudgetAmount = 10000;
        objBg.BudgetYear = 2014;

        objA.AddBudget(objBg);
        AirportDao.SaveOrUpdate(objA);

        objIC.AddBudget(objBg);
        daoFactory.GetInvestmentCodeDao().Save(objIC);  //Error occur here not-null property references a null or transient value Tec.Core.Model.Budget.oInvestmentType


        objIT.AddBudget(objBg);            
        daoFactory.GetInvestmentTypeDao().Save(objIT);
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't bet my life on it.. but I'm going to say your problem is here:

```
public IList<Budget> Budgets {
    get { return new List<Budget>(_lstinvestmentCodeBudgets).AsReadOnly(); }
    protected set { _lstinvestmentCodeBudgets = value; }
}
```

This code is called in this order:

```
objA.AddBudget(objBg);
AirportDao.SaveOrUpdate(objA);
```

`objA` is persisted.. and `objBg` is cascaded and persisted as well. This means there's a reference to `objBg` being tracked by NHiberante.

Then you call this:

```
objIC.AddBudget(objBg);
```

Which adds the budget to the list as expected. Let's call this list "List A".

Then you go to call save:

```
daoFactory.GetInvestmentCodeDao().Save(objIC);
```

When NHibernate starts reading values from your entities.. it comes to your getter:

```
get { return new List<Budget>(_lstInvestmentTypeBudgets).AsReadOnly(); }
```

You've wrapped your property in a new list. So now, this is "List B".. not "List A" as NHibernate expects. "List B" hasn't been persisted.. and so NHibernate says "wait.. you're trying to persist something that I'm not tracking in an UPDATE".

Try changing your getter to this:

```
get { return _lstInvestmentTypeBudgets; }
```

..and see if that works. It should.. because you're returning the same instance.

Comment: I still having same problem event I changed my code as your suggestion by modifying  the code in InvestmentType.cs         `public IList<Budget> Budgets
        {
            get { 
                //return new List<Budget>(_lstInvestmentTypeBudgets).AsReadOnly(); 
                return _lstInvestmentTypeBudgets;
            }
            protected set { _lstInvestmentTypeBudgets = value; }
        }`

Answer (score 0):

The mapping needs a little correction. The Budget is an entity which has the composition reference to the Airport,Investment and InvestmentCode. Budget cannot be added like a child class to the other classes here as there is no One to Many relation here. So please remove the addBudget method from the three classes and add the following Methods to the `Budget` class-> `AddAirport, AddInvestmentCode, AddInvestmentType`. 
Update:
Also correct the mappings accordingly by removing bags pointing to the budget class from Airport,Investment type and code

Comment: Could you please guide me more detail by coding sample?